# Java call a method 'inexplicitly'

Tags: java

If in an abstract base class, there is a public/private method m1 and an abstract method m2, how can I make the method m1 to be executed before the implemented method m2 in the subclass. (Basically I'm trying to put some basic validations in m1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public abstract class Base {
    public boolean m1() {
        // validation stuff
    }
    public final void m2() {
        if (m1()) {
            m2Imp();
        }
    }
    protected abstract void m2Imp();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the base class you can put a method to be the **entry point** of you API for that method:

```
 public void mCaller() {
     m1();
     m2();
 }
```

Then use `mCaller`  instead of calling **m1** and **m2** directly. You can also change visibility of **m1** and **m2** methods.